# `.where` ARel query with enum mapped column returns exclusively entries with `0`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have a model that has an enum for one of its fields.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

   enum status: [:yes, :no, :maybe, :so]

end
```

Status is an integer type field. For any `Foo` records, I can use `foo.yes!, foo.no!` etc and the corresponding record returns true for `foo.yes?, foo.no?` as expected.

However, when I try to query for all `status='no'`, `status='maybe'` or `status='so'` records (with the method `Foo.where(status: 'no')`, `Foo.where(status: 'maybe')`, etc.), it always returns entries that are `status='yes'`. I checked the raw SQL query and it seems to always only query for when `status=0` or when status is `yes`.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord does not provide such an interface for querying enums.
You can query

```
Foo.where(status: 0)
```

Or

```
Foo.yes
```

Answer (score 3):

Because Arel tries to convert provided string to the integer and use that integer in the query. This is expected behaviour.

To solve you problem you may use `Array#index` method:

```
Foo.where(status: Foo.statuses.index('no'))
```

But this approach required only if you use Arel directly. ActiveRecord already cares about it for you.